# Rspec or Rake which one is better

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rake

i have one simple question rspec or rake which one is better and more reliable.

Regards,
AB

Comment: Both are very reliable and better than eachother at what they do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rake is a tool used to manage various tasks related to your application such as updating database schema or adding sample data to it.

RSpec is a tool which helps you write tests for your applications.

Answer (score 5):

RSpec and Rake are two different things.

Both are reliable at what they are intended to do!

Comment: cud u explain it in brief wts the purpose of both this stuff, went through wikipedia cudn't get it though

Answer (score 3):

Apples and Oranges my friend.

Rspec - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSpec

Rake - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rake_(software)

Comment: thx 4 ur reply but rake seems to be giving inconsistent output every time compared to rspec, ie when rspec gives me 0 failures while rake gives errors that to different one after every run.

Comment: Can you share what you're failures / passes are on each way of running the code?

Comment: I suggest becoming familiar with the above wiki-pages and restating your question afterwards.

Comment: while running the rspec spec -p i get 0 failures everytime but while using rake spec i get errors and which is inconsistent errors are like ActiveRecord:JDBCError cannot add or update a child row: a foriegn key constraint.